# Good guide to creating a scalable web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am currently doing c#.net development and I wanted to create a webservice that would work with both my web app and my iphone app.  I would ideally like to work with JSON.  Is there any good guides out there that would help me build a good scalable web service using WCF?  I don't currently have the funds to buy a book so I was hoping a set of online guides could get me to the level of understanding to start coding.  Thanks!

Comment: Times are tough hey, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use WebAPI, the former WCF WebAPI.
Now a part of Microsoft MVC.

Try it!
Loads of online ressources :-)

You can start here : http://www.asp.net/web-api

Basicly; you get a easy-to-use REST API for web applications without the hassle of WCF-configuration.